# python: sigsegv when using ctypes on cygwin

Tags: python, c, cygwin, ctypes, segmentation-fault

I am trying to compile and use a c library in python using ctypes module. The library is strangely working fine on Linux machine but throwing SIGSEGV on Cygwin64.

```
import ctypes
import numpy as np
import pdb

xbry = np.array([0.9, 0.1, 0.2, 0.9])
ybry = np.array([0.9, 0.9, 0.1, 0.1])
beta = np.array([1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0])

nx = 30
ny = 30
ul_idx = 0

nnodes=14
precision=1.0e-12
nppe=3
newton=True
thin=True
checksimplepoly=True
verbose=True

_libgridgen = np.ctypeslib.load_library('libgridgen.dll', '/home/Nikhil/python/octant/gridgen')

print _libgridgen

_libgridgen.gridgen_generategrid2.restype = ctypes.c_void_p
_libgridgen.gridnodes_getx.restype = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double))
_libgridgen.gridnodes_gety.restype = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double))
_libgridgen.gridnodes_getnce1.restype = ctypes.c_int
_libgridgen.gridnodes_getnce2.restype = ctypes.c_int

_libgridgen.gridnodes_getnx.restype = ctypes.c_int
_libgridgen.gridnodes_getny.restype = ctypes.c_int

_libgridgen.gridmap_build.restype = ctypes.c_void_p


nbry = len(xbry)

nsigmas = ctypes.c_int(0)
sigmas = ctypes.c_void_p(0)
nrect = ctypes.c_int(0)
xrect =  ctypes.c_void_p(0)
yrect = ctypes.c_void_p(0)

ngrid = ctypes.c_int(0)
xgrid = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double)()
ygrid = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double)()

_gn = _libgridgen.gridgen_generategrid2(
 ctypes.c_int(nbry), 
 (ctypes.c_double * nbry)(*xbry), 
 (ctypes.c_double * nbry)(*ybry), 
 (ctypes.c_double * nbry)(*beta),
 ctypes.c_int(ul_idx), 
 ctypes.c_int(nx), 
 ctypes.c_int(ny), 
 ngrid, 
 xgrid, 
 ygrid,
 ctypes.c_int(nnodes), 
 ctypes.c_int(newton), 
 ctypes.c_double(precision),
 ctypes.c_int(checksimplepoly), 
 ctypes.c_int(thin), 
 ctypes.c_int(nppe),
 ctypes.c_int(verbose),
 ctypes.byref(nsigmas), 
 ctypes.byref(sigmas), 
 ctypes.byref(nrect),
 ctypes.byref(xrect), 
 ctypes.byref(yrect) )


 print 'run getx'
 x = _libgridgen.gridnodes_getx(_gn)

 print 'reshape result.'
 x = np.asarray([x[0][i] for i in range(ny*nx)])
 x.shape = (ny, nx)


 print 'run gety'
 y = _libgridgen.gridnodes_gety(_gn)

 print 'reshape result.'
 y = np.asarray([y[0][i] for i in range(ny*nx)])
 y.shape = (ny, nx)
```

## backtrace

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000542596595 in gridnodes_getx (gn=0x45ab50) at gridnodes.c:789
789         return gn->gx;
(gdb) backtrace
0  0x0000000542596595 in gridnodes_getx (gn=0x45ab50) at gridnodes.c:789
```

and this is the c code backtrace is referring to

```
int gridnodes_getnx(gridnodes* gn)
{
    return gn->nx;
}

int gridnodes_getny(gridnodes* gn)
{
    return gn->ny;
}

double** gridnodes_getx(gridnodes* gn)
{
    return gn->gx;
}

double** gridnodes_gety(gridnodes* gn)
{
    return gn->gy;
}
```

I would appreciate if some one can help me with this.

Comment: You're not setting `gridnodes_getx.argtypes = (ctypes.c_void_p,)`, so the `gn` argument is passed as a 32-bit `int`. If it's a 64-bit process, this potentially truncates the pointer value.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue by using a class

```
class gridnodes (ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
    ('nx',ctypes.c_int), \
    ('ny',ctypes.c_int), \
    ('gx', ctypes.c_double), \
    ('gy', ctypes.c_double)]
```

and replacing

```
_libgridgen.gridgen_generategrid2.restype = ctypes.c_void_p
```

by

```
_libgridgen.gridgen_generategrid2.restype = ctypes.POINTER(gridnodes)
```

I also tried the suggestion by @eryksun and that works as well..

Comment: i cant accept my answer for two days..would be great if someone can accept and close the issue.

Comment: If your design wants to keep the `gridnodes` type opaque, you can just use a `Structure` subclass without `_fields_`. Using a subclass of `c_void_p` would also work since subclasses of simple types aren't automatically converted to native Python types.